# XPAGES: Build path contains duplicate entry: 'org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER'

Tags: eclipse, xpages, xpages-extlib

I am trying to run an Xpage locally (in Chrome if it makes any difference) from a local NSF and am receiving the error:

Build path contains duplicate entry: 'org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER'

I have copied all the ExtLib Features and Plugins to the correct directories as required.

Anonymous is set to Author.

I cannot find any information on how to resolve this. There was an open ticket on OpenNTF 6 years ago but no resolution.

Comment: Have you tried removing the database entirely from your workspace and designer, and then re-adding the database and then cleaning. I have had this fix issues that just cleaning did not fix.

Comment: I have deleted the local copy, recreated it from the server copy (File - Application - New Copy), opened it in Designer, Cleaned and Built it with the same results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Update]

[As Jesse Gallagher pointed out on Twitter](https://twitter.com/Gidgerby/status/697197478018445312), you can access the `.classpath` file without going through the ODP setup via the Navigator perspective. I would still recommend setting up source control since it gives you:

- local change history in DDE (even if you don't use the ODP in git/hg)
- the ability to track any changing file during development, aka- a rogue change to your `.classpath` file (I recommend installing [Cameron Gregor's Swiper plugin](https://openntf.org/main.nsf/project.xsp?r=project/Swiper))
- is fairly easy to set up
- as a developer, version control is *the* best way to cover your butt

[image: dotClasspath file accessible via Navigator perspective]

[/Update]

I believe you *quite literally* have a duplicate entry in your NSF's build class path. This has to do with the Eclipse version Domino Designer is based on is being confused by its defined class path. I recommend the following:

- if you don't have it set up already, set up source control for your NSF
- open the (hidden) file `.classpath`, which can be found in the root of your On Disk Project (ODP) folder with a trusty text editor (Notepad++, etc.)
- search for *org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER*
- if you find more than one, you will need to deconflict your class path (aka- remove one; it may be best to make a backup of the file)
- if you don't have "Build Automatically" checked (in your Project menu), you may need to open Package Explorer and right-click your ODP, then perform a "Sync with NSF"

You should be able to de-conflict your build path via the Project > Build Path screen, but this is an easy way to search the whole thing in one shot.

[Here's an example the `.classpath` file](https://github.com/edm00se/AnAppOfIceAndFire/blob/master/ODP/.classpath) from a working app.
[image: example of correctly defined class path, no duplicates]

An example of [a situation where others (using gradle, in this case) ran into](https://issues.gradle.org/browse/GRADLE-1315) a duplicate issue with *org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER*.
[image: example of a class path file with duplicate entry for org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER]

Setting up source control with an NSF, right-click NSF, Team Development, Set Up Source Control:
[image: setting up source control]

Note: If you need a little more info on how to set up source control or want to know more about where to park the ODP (aka- if you haven't done this before), I recommend checking out David Leedy's [Notes in 9 episode 131: Using SourceTree for Better XPages Source Control](http://www.notesin9.com/2013/11/12/notesin9-131-use-sourcetree-for-better-xpages-source-control/). Even if you don't use SourceTree, it's worth it to understand that the ODP should not be placed in your Notes Data directory, etc.

Comment: Thak you Eric. I will see if the client is open to setting up Source Control in the environment. In the meantime, I will look at the .classpath and see if that holds a clue to the problem.

Comment: Worst case you can do source control on your personal dev machine.  You don't have to have a server but usually it makes sense.  Even if the client "doesn't want it" - and they're stupid if they don't.  You could run it locally and you still gain some protection and the ability to switch branches easily.

Comment: What @DavidLeedy said.